# SELinux: cannot restore segment prot after reloc: Permission denied

Tags: c++, linux, selinux, relocation

We are testing our application in SELinux environment. Now, we are getting the following error:

```
dlopen failed to load libFoo.so -libFoo.so: cannot restore segment prot after reloc: Permission denied
```

As far as I understand from [my searches](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/SELinux_FAQ/index.html#faq-entry-unconfined_t), this is related to relocations in `.text` section in the shared library. As far as I can see, we are already using `-fPIC` for all of our shared libraries. Though there are possibly some static libraries also linked into those shared libraries.

How can I find out what relocations/symbols are causing this error to pop up? What should I look for in `nm` or `objdump -rR` output for the shared library?

Or am I fishing for wrong information and the problem lies somewhere else than the produced relocations in the shared library?

Comment: Well, not a whole hour later and I have found this: http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/textrelocs.html, which basically boils down to use `eu-findtextrel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this: http://akkadia.org/drepper/textrelocs.html, which basically boils down to a suggestion to use `eu-findtextrel` to see what text relocations do exist. Recompiling affected libraries with `-fPIC` then fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I thought this was good advice because it did not set SELinux to permissive mode.

You can also from [here](http://www.cubrid.org/wiki_tutorials/entry/cannot-restore-segment-prot-after-reloc-permission-denied).

```
chcon -t texrel_shlib_t <lib>
```

So for instance

```
chcon -t texrel_shlib_t libmylib.so
```

But, this is still getting around SELinux so -fPIC is the way to do it. I had some problems because I incorrectly put -fPIC in in the linker flags. -fPIC is a compiler option!